# GT-ITM Tool `itm': double free or corruption (top)

Tags: networking, ubuntu-16.04, ns2

I'm new with ns simulator. Today, I keep following below site for installing ns 2.35 in Ubuntu 16.04 x64
http://telecom-academy.blogspot.com/2018/02/install-network-simulator-2-ns2.35-in-ubuntu-16.04-step-by-step.html.
After install completely, I tried to use gt-itm tool to generate a randome network topology with 10 nodes. So I executed a command like this:

> $ itm r10

Where r10's content as shown as below

```
geo 3 
10 10 3 .2
```

Eventually, I obtained the error like the following:

```
*** Error in `itm': double free or corruption (top): 0x0000000000bbe250 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f9f067607e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f9f0676937a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f9f0676d53c]
itm[0x406b27]
itm[0x401b0a]
itm[0x401cf5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f9f06709830]
itm[0x400f49]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0040b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1443751                            /usr/local/bin/itm
0060a000-0060b000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 1443751                            /usr/local/bin/itm
0060b000-0060c000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 1443751                            /usr/local/bin/itm
0060c000-0060d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00bbd000-00bde000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f9f00000000-7f9f00021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9f00021000-7f9f04000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9f064d3000-7f9f064e9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6296370                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f9f064e9000-7f9f066e8000 ---p 00016000 08:01 6296370                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f9f066e8000-7f9f066e9000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 6296370                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f9f066e9000-7f9f068a9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6296332                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f9f068a9000-7f9f06aa9000 ---p 001c0000 08:01 6296332                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f9f06aa9000-7f9f06aad000 r--p 001c0000 08:01 6296332                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f9f06aad000-7f9f06aaf000 rw-p 001c4000 08:01 6296332                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f9f06aaf000-7f9f06ab3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9f06ab3000-7f9f06bbb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6296402                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f9f06bbb000-7f9f06dba000 ---p 00108000 08:01 6296402                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f9f06dba000-7f9f06dbb000 r--p 00107000 08:01 6296402                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f9f06dbb000-7f9f06dbc000 rw-p 00108000 08:01 6296402                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f9f06dbc000-7f9f06de2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6296304                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f9f06fc4000-7f9f06fc8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9f06fe0000-7f9f06fe1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9f06fe1000-7f9f06fe2000 r--p 00025000 08:01 6296304                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f9f06fe2000-7f9f06fe3000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 6296304                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f9f06fe3000-7f9f06fe4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffe9d89b000-7ffe9d8bd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffe9d953000-7ffe9d956000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffe9d956000-7ffe9d958000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Also, I tried to use: export MALLOC_CHECK_=0 for removing the error log. Instead I got a mesh network topology. Which I want is a random network topology not a mesh. So anyone can help me solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Current output:

```
EDGES (from-node to-node length a b):
0 9
0 8
0 7
....
0 3
0 2
0 1
1 9
1 8
1 7
...
1 2
2 9
2 8
2 7
...
8 9
```

But what I expect is generating randomly like belows:

```
EDGES (from-node to-node length a b):
0 9
0 4
0 2 
1 8
2 6
3 9
3 8
3 5
4 7
4 6
5 9
5 7
7 9
8 9
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include OS name, version, architecture. ( Like Ubuntu 16.04 - amd64.)

Answer (score 0):

My test :

```
cd ns-2.35/gt-itm/bin/
./itm r20    // where r20 is a 19B text file with your code
```

The files {`r20-0.gb 5.4kB, r20-1.gb 5.1kB, r20-2.gb 5.3kB`} are created.

Your link https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ns2-network-simulator-on-ubuntu-14.04/ *is old information*. Latest is : `ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz`
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing → With the updated `gt-itm` from `ns-allinone-2.36.rc1.tar.gz` (2017 update). And with the g++-5.4 updates in `ns-2.35/` (2014 update).

**Note** : Please be aware that ns-2.35/ must be compiled with g++-5.4 or earlier, e.g. g++-4.8 . ( Example build command for ns-allinone-2.35 : `export CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 && ./install` )

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I download the latest file from your shared repo, but after run `./install`. There is no compiled file in `ns-allinone-2.35/bin` or `gt-itm/bin`. Currently, I compile with default gcc-5.4.0 in Ubuntu 16.04. I also updated my description.

Comment: Well, it seems the only OS that can still do `gt-itm` is PCLinuxOS-2018. Used to work → Posts #4, #5 here → https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/problem-compiling-gt-itm-ns-on-ubuntu-15-04-64-bit-4175599305/#4 .... I just did a try with some OS´s, 32 and 64bits : Ubuntu 12.04, 15.04, CentOS 6.10, etc.   , etc. : No luck. Please continue with `export MALLOC_CHECK_=0`

Comment: Thank you, I tried and I removed the error log but what I expect is a random network topology instead of mesh as current output of gt-itm in my machine.

Comment: May be you mean "convert the current files to network files" ? ... My file test ... Ref. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwiyvJ69uczeAhVGkywKHUaUD4oQFjACegQIBxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2F140.136.149.173%2Flab%2FTeaching%2520Activities%2FMobile%2520Communication%2FNetwork%2520Topology(gt-itm).ppt&usg=AOvVaw1l6widQqyDOSV8sPjLfSCQ ... ... I.e. use `sgb2ns` by means of the script  `[name]Runconvert2Tcl.csh` : Result = `test2__gt-itm-hdng.tar.gz` → https://www.dropbox.com/s/abggywzxdmzxucj/test2__gt-itm-hdng.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: ... And a test with your `r20` : **./_R20-Runconvert2Tcl.csh** and '_r20-Runeval.csh' → result → `test0-r20_gt-itm_hdng.tar.gz` https://www.dropbox.com/s/cp1t3y1wvkbeaes/test0-r20_gt-itm_hdng.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: You seem to get the same results with me. The results showed the topology of a mesh network. It means that one arbitrary node is connected to all rest nodes. But I don't want such a mesh network. I want to generate a random network in which from one arbitrary node, there is only a number of specific connections to other nodes with a probability 0.2. Please take a look at my updated question. Thanks